# How to add or update Identity Provider details without restarting the app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, owin

I'm using .NET 4.6 with OWIN Context to configure app security. The app supports multiple identity providers, which I'm adding in the Startup.Auth.cs file like this:

```
private static void AddOidcProviders(IAppBuilder app, IEnumerable<IdentityProviderDetails> allProviders)
{
    var oidcProviders = allProviders.Where(x => x.ProviderType == IdpProvidersConstants.OpenIdConnect);
    foreach (var oidcProvider in oidcProviders)
    {
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            //provider specific config
        });
    }
}
```

The problem with the code above is that it runs only once - during the app start-up. Since I keep those providers details in the database, they can change unexpectedly. Is it possible to add more providers and/or update existing ones without restarting the app pool?
I've tried injecting AppBuilder to HomeController and re run the AddOidcProviders, but the providers details are not updated.